# Virtualbox remote display updates remote as well as local screen

Tags: virtualbox

Folks,

I am running Virtualbox on Windows 7. The guest OS also is Windows 7.

I configured rdp connection at port 5000 (as stated in the documentation) and am able to connect to ip:5000 using Microsoft Remote Desktop client.

However, the problem is that the screen of the guest VM is simultaneously being shown on both, local as well as remote, windows.

Is there a way to just close the local window without shutting down the VM itself? Perhaps something similar to headless virtualbox on Linux.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can start a Virtualbox VM without GUI from the command line using:

```
VBoxHeadless --startvm [vmname]
```

There is also a section about running headless VMs in the Virtualbox manual: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the `VBoxManage startvm` command with the `--type` option is superior to `VBoxHeadless` as the former doesn't require the command prompt window to remain open (which largely defeats the purpose I think).

Below is and example of its output:

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" startvm "My Virtual Machine" --type headless
Waiting for VM "My Virtual Machine" to power on...
VM "My Virtual Machine" has been successfully started.

C:\>
```

Note that control is returned to the common prompt, allowing it to be closed without terminating the instance. The VM's status will also still be reported by the VirtualBox GUI.

The `VBoxManage startvm` command is documented [in chapter 8 of the VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-startvm).